# WCF NetTcpBinding application creating many thousands of .NET threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

We have a WCF service with a `NetTcpBinding` homegrown application. It works fine most of the time but from time to time it starts creating dot net threads as fast as it can. The CLR dies quickly but it will keep creating threads until it runs out of memory or cpu...over 10,000 at times. Of course, the application was dead long before it gets there.  We recycle the windows service it runs as and it goes back to normal until the next time.

We have Dynatrace and it catches the thread creation increase but the CLR crashes very early in the process and we can not get a thread dump of the problem.  I will try to catch it earlier but so far, no luck.

What other tools could we leave running all the time without impacting the application, that would help us determine why this is happening?

It may be many days between these events, it might occur during the night when no one is monitoring it, so automated info collection would be useful. But we will look into anything.

Also, any idea what might be causing this in a general way?

Thanks for any help you could provide.

Comment: oh, it is c#.   Might help to know that I guess.

Comment: Could you please include a code snippet that will recreate the issue in your question? I doubt I will be able to help, but being able to recreate the problem will make it easier for others to answer your question

Comment: I would if I could.  We have no idea where it is occurring.  It is a pretty big application.   It can go many days or weeks without occurring.  Then it can happen several times a day at times.